# Convrt daetime stom timestamp failed due to module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert `DateTime` from `string`, this is what i have try:

```
from datetime import datetime

given_date_time_obj = datetime.fromisoformat('2019-03-13 17:35:38,837', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

**And (i am sing python 3**)

```
given_date_time_obj = datetime.fromisoformat('2019-03-13 17:35:38,837')
```

And got this `error`:

> given_date_time_obj = datetime.fromisoformat('2019-03-13
>   17:35:38,837', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') AttributeError: module
>   'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

Comment: fromisoformat is not in datetime, its in date.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat should work in python version >= 3.7 What is the python version that you are using?

Comment: i am using 3.7.2

Comment: So read the answer below. It worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

> classmethod datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
>   Return a datetime corresponding to a date_string in one of the formats emitted by date.isoformat() and datetime.isoformat(). Specifically, this function supports strings in the format(s) YYYY-MM-DD[*HH[:MM[:SS[.fff[fff]]]][+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]]], where * can match any single character.

Caution This does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it is only intended as the inverse operation of datetime.isoformat().

**New in version 3.7.**

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Code

```
from datetime import datetime
given_date_time_obj = datetime.fromisoformat('2019-03-13 17:35:38,837')
```

Output

```
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2019-03-13 17:35:38,837'
```

Comment: So how can i use it ?

Comment: OK but i did not understand why this cause and how to fix it

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Did you manage to run the code or do you still face 'AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat' ? This code works on my computer.  `from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.fromisoformat("2014-01-09T21:48:00-05:30")
print(x)

datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 21, 48, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=66600)))`

Comment: So use https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version in your code and check the python version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my code can be used instead:

```
import re, datetime
def fromisoformat(formatstr):
    return datetime.datetime(*[int(a) for a in re.split('\D', formatstr)])
```